# Connectivity Issue with StackExchange.Redis 1.2.6

Tags: caching, redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I am trying to implement Azure Redis Cache in my existing ASP.NET Web Application.
Its build in **.NET Framework 4.5**

Compatible Option of StackExchange.Redis nuget package is 1.2.6
When i install and use the same, it gives error: "Not able to Connect"

Just by changing my application to build in .NET Framework 4.6 and not even updating StackExchange.Redis to latest compatible version, my code start working.

I cannot change .NET Framework of my Web application.
Please help.

Is here anyone who have faced this issue?

Comment: Exception: UnableToConnect on <cachename>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Interactive, origin: ResetNonConnected, input-buffer: 0, outstanding: 0, last-read: 5s ago, last-write: 5s ago, unanswered-write: 39878s ago, keep-alive: 60s, pending: 0, state: Connecting, last-heartbeat: never, last-mbeat: -1s ago, global: 5s ago, mgr: Inactive, err: never

Answer (score 0):

You can see my demo first. I can use `StackExchange.Redis 1.2.6` in `.NET Framework 4.5` project. You can [download my demo for test](https://github.com/Jason446620/redisandframework45), you just need to paste your connectionstr. If no ssl, you also need to change port to `6379`.

[image]

My `CacheConnection` like below. No SSL cert.

```
<add key="CacheConnection" value="pans******he.redis.cache.windows.net:6379,password=*********,ssl=False,abortConnect=False,allowAdmin=true"/>
```

***Why add `,allowAdmin=true`, becase below code.***

```
var server = Connection.GetServer(endpoint.Host, endpoint.Port);
var clients = server.ClientList();
```